# Loop through Nested Array of Objects, Rendering Different Markup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, reduce

I hit a rabbit hole with a `React` app. I'm `looping` through this array of objects:

```
const weeklyClasses = [
  {
    id: 1,
    day: "Monday",
    classDescription: [
      { classType: "11am-12pm Jazz", teacher: "Joe" },
      { classType: "1pm-2pm Blues", teacher: "Doe" },
      { classType: "3pm-4pm Samba", teacher: "Zen" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    day: "Tuesday",
    classDescription: [
      { classType: "11am-12pm Rock", teacher: "Sis" },
      { classType: "1pm-2pm Tango", teacher: "Ter" },
      { classType: "3pm-4pm Salsa", teacher: "Soul" }
    ]
  },
  // ...
];
```

I am looping and retrieving the desired values, however, currently the `classType` outputs as one `p`

```
const Data = () => {
  return weeklyClasses.map((o, i) => {
    return (
      <div className="classDay" key={o.id}>
        {o.day}
        <div className="classType">
          {o.classType}
          //Right here
          <p>{o.classDescription.map(i => i.classType)}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
};
```

How can I output **each** `classType` as **diff** `p` tags?

Is it okay to be mapping on a map? (Should I, How could I) use reduce instead?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than wrapping the entire array of descriptions into a single `p`:

```
<p>{o.classDescription.map(i => i.classType)}</p>
```

You can wrap each class description element into a `p` instead:

```
{o.classDescription.map(i => <p>{i.classType}</p> )}
{/*                          ^^^             ^^^^  */}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! Is it okay to be mapping on a map? Should I reduce it instead?

Comment: @NullisTrue If by "mapping on a map", you mean nested mapping, that is perfectly fine. It isn't anything bad and is in fact quite common. Technically what the inner map is doing is just mapping a small portion of a nested element, not doing a map of the entire mapped element but either way, this is perfectly fine. Reduction is used more when you want to reduce a collection to a single value. This isn't the case here, you want to map a collection of javascript objects to a collection of JSX elements showing some values from those objects.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.